How to Configure Tridion Content Delivery API in a Spring Boot Application Using Username and Password
I am working on integrating Tridion Content Delivery API with a Spring Boot application. I have the Tridion username and password, but I am unsure about the configuration steps required to set up the Content Delivery API within a Spring Boot project.
Could someone provide a detailed guide or example on how to:

Configure Tridion Content Delivery API in a Spring Boot application.

Use the provided Tridion username and password for authentication.

Properly integrate and make API calls to retrieve content.


Any advice or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!
I need

A clear guide or example on how to configure the Tridion Content Delivery API in a Spring Boot application.

An example of making API calls to retrieve content from Tridion, including any necessary configuration for authentication and request setup.


